# Filtering columns in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hello everyone i've a code who gives me the output of the command "show vlan brief" on a cisco switch.

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import pandas as pd

file1 =  open ("./iptest.txt", "r")
lines = file1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    NetworkDevice = {"host": f"{line}",
             "username": "username",
             "password": "mdp",
             "device_type": "cisco_ios",

   }
    Connect = ConnectHandler(**NetworkDevice)

    Connect.enable()
    command = "sh vl br"
    fin = print(Connect.send_command(command))
    #dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list(fin))
    #rslt_df = dataframe.loc[dataframe['Ports'] != ""]
    
    #print('\nResult dataframe :\n', rslt_df)
```

I've the output below and i'd like to get the same but with hiding "Ports" columns when it's empty.

Is that possible ?
I tried with pandas but too hard for me atm, i'm a noob in python

Thanks for answer ! :)

```
VLAN Name                             Status    Ports
---- -------------------------------- --------- ------------------
1    default                          active    Gi0/3, Gi0/4, Gi0/5
2    Test1                            active    
4    Test2                            active    
5    Test3                            active    
6    Test4                            active    
7    Test5                            active    
8    Test6                            active    Gi0/1
```

UPDATE :

First, thanks for your answer it's so sweet from you and that's exactly the output I wanted :)

So, I tried with this code :

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fin), sep="\s{2,}", engine='python', skiprows=2, header=None)
df.columns = re.split('\s+', fin.split('\n', 1)[0]) # getting headers
df.set_index('VLAN', inplace=True) # if it's more convenient to use VLAN as index (optional)
print(df[~df['Ports'].isna()])
```

But it returns me a pandas error that i corrected with error_bad_lines=False

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fin), sep="\s{2,}", engine='python', skiprows=2, header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
```

I get an other error : **KeyError: "None of ['VLAN'] are in the columns"**

So, like u said it's optionnal and I decided to comment the line to do my tests

At the end I've the error **KeyError: 'Ports'**
After all the morning on this issue I can't find how to declare it proprely in the code

The code I currently have is :

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fin), sep="\s{2,}", engine='python', skiprows=2, header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
df.columns = re.split('\s+', fin.split('\n', 1)[0]) # getting headers
#df.set_index('VLAN', inplace=True) # if it's more convenient to use VLAN as index (optional)
print(df[~df['Ports'].isna()])
```

And the output of this is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\PROGRAMMES\PROJET_VLAN\vlans.py", line 26, in <module>
    print(df[~df['Ports'].isna()])
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Ports'
```

I thank you if you could help me a bit :)

UPDATE 2 :

This is the final code causing the error **ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 4 elements**

```
import re
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

switches=[]

file1 =  open ("./iptest.txt", "r")
lines = file1.readlines()
for line in lines:
    NetworkDevice = {"host": f"{line}",
                 "username": "admin",
                 "password": "mdp",
                 "device_type": "cisco_ios",

    }
    Connect = ConnectHandler(**NetworkDevice)

    Connect.enable()
    command = "sh vl br"
    fin = Connect.send_command(command).strip('\n')
    print(fin)

    
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fin), sep="\s{2,}", engine='python', skiprows=2, header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
    df.columns = re.split('\s+', fin.split('\n', 1)[0])
    final = df[~df['Ports'].isna()]
    final1 = f"\nSWICTH IP : {line} \n" + final.to_string()
    switches.append(final1)
    

with open(r".\output.txt","w") as filout:
            for j in switches:
                filout.write(f"{j}\n")
```

Working on some switches, and error on some others (which are the same)

Full error message :

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fin), sep="\s{2,}", engine='python', skiprows=2, header=None, error_bad_lines=False)
Skipping line 11: Expected 3 fields in line 11, saw 4. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
Skipping line 72: Expected 3 fields in line 72, saw 4. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
Skipping line 76: Expected 3 fields in line 76, saw 4. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\PROGRAMMES\PROJET_VLAN\vlans copy.py", line 26, in <module>
    df.columns = re.split('\s+', fin.split('\n', 1)[0])
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5588, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)
  File "pandas\_libs\properties.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 769, in _set_axis
    self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 214, in set_axis
    self._validate_set_axis(axis, new_labels)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\base.py", line 69, in _validate_set_axis
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 4 elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the `print` function returns `None` so you should do:

```
fin = Connect.send_command(command).strip()
print(fin)
```

Edit: you might have leading empty lines in `fin`, so remove them with `strip`

Then you'll have to parse `fin` as a csv with pandas. It's a bit tricky cause the separators are two or more whitespaces, except for the headers:

```
import re
from io import StringIO

header = re.split('\s+', fin.split('\n', 1)[0]) # getting headers

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(fin), sep="\s{2,}", engine='python', skiprows=2, names=header)

df.set_index('VLAN', inplace=True) # if it's more convenient to use VLAN as index (optional)
print(df[~df['Ports'].isna()])
```

Edit 2: getting headers *before* parsing csv, otherwise pandas might expect wrong number of columns.

Output:

```
         Name  Status                Ports
VLAN                                      
1     default  active  Gi0/3, Gi0/4, Gi0/5
8       Test6  active                Gi0/1
```

Comment: I edited my answer as well with the command `fin = Connect.send_command(command).strip()` see if it works

Comment: If I can ask you something again...
It's working very well on many switches, but for the some reasons , on other many switches (which are exactly the same) i've an error.
**ValueError: Lenght mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 4 elements**

Do you know from where it can come ? 
Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe whitespaces from the last cell are stripped too. Try replacing `strip()` with `strip('\n')`. Let me know if it works and I'll change the answer accordingly!

Comment: That give me the same error, 
I tried with many other parameters but still the same error

Comment: Would you share `fin` causing the error?

Comment: I meant what's the value of `fin` causing the error? It should be printed right before your error message.

Comment: Oh ok ! 
`fin` is printed correctly and showed me all the VLANs before the filter.
I've the print, and just after that, the error